# SXSSFWorkbook and XSSFSheet

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-charts

I need to generate a multi sheet excel report, one sheet has the main table and it can get quite large so using SXSSFWorkbook makes sense, on the other hand in another sheet I need to put few charts and I haven't seen such option with SXSSFSheet (only with XSSFSheets), is it possible to have and XSSFSheet in SXSSFWorkbook or is there an workaround?

I am using apache poi 4.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out SXSSFWorkbook can be a decorator of XSSFWorkbook, so you can add sheets via anyone of them (I wouldn't push this method to its limits, but for me it worked):

```
    XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(xssfWorkbook...

    XSSFSheet sheet = xssfWorkbook.createSheet...
```